# Unable to concatenate with apache spark function to_timestamp() on Databricks using PySpark and add a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to using concatenate with the to_timestamp() on a Apache Spark table and add a columns using the .withColumn function but it won't work.

The code is as follows:

```
DIM_WORK_ORDER.withColumn("LAST_MODIFICATION_DT", to_timestamp(concat(col('LAST_MOD_DATE'), lit(' '), col('LAST_MOD_TIME')), 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss'))
```

The result I would expect to see is something like

LAST_MODIFICATION_DT | WORK_ORDER

However, I'm getting the following result:

[image]

Some data to work with:

WORK_ORDER  LAST_MOD_TIME
10000008    null
11358186    142254
10000007    193402
10000009    null

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please give us an input that can be copied([not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)) and an expected output so people can work with it. Currently we cannot reproduce this using the image, in short please add the shortest code to reproduce this problem..

Comment: Hi anky, I've added some input. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know in Spark, dataframes are immutable. Hence, once you have created a dataframe, it can't change.

```
%python
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("<input file path>")
df1 = df.withColumn("LAST_MODIFICATION_DT", to_timestamp(concat(col('LAST_MOD_DATE'), lit(' '), col('LAST_MOD_TIME')), 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss'))
display(df1)
```

I am getting below output as expected. If this is not what you expect, please provide more info

[image]